# Making collection view cells like Pinterest's tag

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

What I want are cells that are scrollable horizontally as Pinterest.

I looked into many tuotrial but I could not find any.
I tired changing the layout's flow , scroll direction but it didn't work!
I will be very happy if somebody can give me a hand. :)

[image: tags are in the upper part]

Comment: image http://i.imgur.com/9ed9F1j.gif

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23861238/1402846